# disable the reordering of rows in a NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nstableview

I need to disable the reordering of rows in a NSTableView so that when I open the application data of the NSTableView are in the same order in which I created them.

Comment: Are you using Cocoa bindings? Is the NSTableView bound to a NSArrayController?

Comment: yes, the table uses the bindings and the tableview is connected to a arraycontroller.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable sorting in NSTableVIew?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311334/how-to-disable-sorting-in-nstableview)

Answer (score 1):

In Inspector, check the bindings of the sorted table column, select value and check that the option "Creates Sort Descriptor" in unchecked.

Comment: I disabled the voice you indicated in all columns of the tableview, but it clears up in alphabetical order.

Comment: I think you should define a new NSDate attribute in your entity, put the current date when creating new records, define a sort descriptor based on the attribute and fetch the date using the sort descriptor.

Comment: does not exist simpler and cleaner way?