# disable sorting NSTableView button

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, xcode6, nstableview

I implementing a NSTableView but I want to disable sorting button:

[image]

I have tried:

```
   [self.tagTableView setAllowsColumnReordering:NO];
```

But doesn't work.Also I have look all over interface builder but I haven't found a way disable the sorting button. Any of you knows how can I disable the sorting button?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: put some code what you have done.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311334/how-to-disable-sorting-in-nstableview

Same description, Same question!

Comment: Is not the same question. I want to disable the sorting button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these function
[table setIsSortable:NO]

Comment: It seems like setIsSortable is deprecated